# Regarding data in forward mail

Tags: email, gmail, jakarta-mail, html-email

In java mail Api(mail.jar). when an forward mail is fetched using IMAP protocol. for an forwarded message it contains object of IMAPNestedMessage which contains 2 parts for simple message. First part have simple data and second part contains same data with html.
Now the same data is repeated twice in mail. Can anyone tell me why this is occuring.

For ex:
hello is a text forwarded by user.

part 1 : hello 
part 2:     hello

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking at a multipart/alternative message.  See RFC 2046 for the definition of multipart/alternative.  This should have nothing to do with whether the message has been forwarded or not.